# Can not log in a user into Realm Object Server (locally on my mac)

Tags: ios, swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I am new to Realm and following the basic tutorial for creating a simple ToDo app for iOS in their official web page [here](https://docs.realm.io/sync/getting-started-1/ios-quick-start/step-2-adding-query-based-sync). In my first view controller's `viewDidAppear()` method I have the following code:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    title = "Welcome"

    if let _ = SyncUser.current {
        // We have already logged in here
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(ProjectsViewController(), animated: true)
    } else {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Login to Realm Cloud", message: "Supply a nice nickname!", preferredStyle: .alert)

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Login", style: .default, handler: {[unowned self] (alert) in

            let textField = alertController.textFields![0] as UITextField
            let creds = SyncCredentials.nickname(textField.text!)

            SyncUser.logIn(with: creds, server: Constants.AUTH_URL, onCompletion: {[weak self] (user, err) in

                if let _ = user {
                    self?.navigationController?.pushViewController(ProjectsViewController(), animated: true)

                } else if let error = err {
                    fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            })
        }))

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.placeholder = "A name for your user"
        }

        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

The AUTH_URL is the url to my local host.
For some reason, when I try to log in I get the error:

> Error Domain=io.realm.sync.auth Code=601 "Your request parameters did not validate. provider: Unknown provider!;" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Your request parameters did not validate. provider: Unknown provider!;}

I couldn't find anything specific, related to that error.

I've also tried to download the completed project for the tutorial, and when I run it with my local host I get another error:

> Error Domain=io.realm.sync.auth Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={statusCode=400}

Please, can anyone explain why am I getting these errors? I guess, they have something to do with the local host address. But I can open the page for the object server with that address on my browser without any error. 
Thanks in advance.

**EDITED**

When I use Realm Cloud and the instance URL there, it works fine. Now I am pretty sure that the problem is related to the IP address that I am providing. However, I can't find out what is exactly wrong with it.

Comment: the "AUTH_URL" is 'http://localhost"? try to put your IP address instead (ifconfig)

Comment: @MabroukiFakhri, it is the IP address. Initially it was "localhost" but I read that the actual IP address is required. I know that this question might sound simple but on the browser I see the following for the ROS http://127.0.0.1:9080 (which is also provided as the default one in the tutorial) and I am not quite sure whether I should use it or the actual IP address of my computer.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 == localhost ^^' try to use the ip address of your computer and be sure that everything is connected in the same network (your phone if you are using your phone for tests)

Comment: @MabroukiFakhri, thanks for the explanation :). I've tried to use "my_actual_ip_address:9080" and the result is the same (the first error log from the question). Currently, I am using the simulator for test purposes.

Comment: I believe you need to use the FQDN of your ROS server with the following format *static let MY_INSTANCE_ADDRESS = "http://127.0.0.1:9080"* which then populates the AUTH_URL. Then, try hard-coding your SyncCredentials and set yourself as admin like this. *let creds = SyncCredentials.nickname("Jay", isAdmin: true)*